# Find connected groups over levels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

A node A has 3 connected Nodes B1, B2, B3. Those Bx Nodes have again connected Nodes C1,C2,C3 and C4. Also Node A have 2 connected nodes C5 and C6.

Starting with node A I want to collect all C-nodes. I did a query for the A node, collect the two C-Nodes, then a query for the B-nodes, collect again all C-nodes and merge both arrays. Work but is not very clever.

I tried (Pseudocode)

```
MATCH (g)<-[:IS_SUBGROUP_OF*1]-(i)-[:HAS_C_NODES]->(c) WHERE g = A.uuid  RETURN C_NODES
```

But I get either all c-nodes for A or for the B-nodes

How would I do a query that collects all C-Nodes starting with Node A?

*** edited *** 
Here is some example data:

```
CREATE (a:A), (b1:B1), (b2:B2), (b3:B3), (c1:C1), (c2:C2), (c3:C3), (c4:C4), (a)-[r:HAS]->(c4), (a)-[r1:HAS]->(b1), (a)-[r2:HAS]->(b2), (a)-[r3:HAS]->(b3), (b1)-[r4:HAS]->(c1), (b1)-[r5:HAS]->(c2), (b2)-[r6:HAS]->(c3)
```

A query should return all nodes starting with C, no matter to which node they are connected (A or B).

Comment: It would be better if you show an example of input data, the desired result and how are you trying to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add multiple labels for each node. You should use this to your advantage and segregate all the B and C nodes into a second label.

Eg:

```
CREATE (a:A), (b1:B1:BType), (b2:B2:BType), (b3:B3:BType), (c1:C1:CType), (c2:C2:CType), (c3:C3:CType), (c4:C4:CType), (a)-[r:HAS]->(c4), (a)-[r1:HAS]->(b1), (a)-[r2:HAS]->(b2), (a)-[r3:HAS]->(b3), (b1)-[r4:HAS]->(c1), (b1)-[r5:HAS]->(c2), (b2)-[r6:HAS]->(c3)
```

I have modified your create statement to group all the B nodes as :BType label and all the C nodes as :CType label.

You can simply use the optional match keyword to selectively traverse through the relationships if they exist and obtain the results you want.

```
match (a:A)-[:HAS]->(b:BType)-[:HAS]->(c:CType) optional match (a:A)-[:HAS]->(xc:CType) return c,xc
```

If you would like both sets of nodes to be grouped together you could try this statement instead which uses collect().

```
match (a:A)-[:HAS]->(b:BType)-[:HAS]->(c:CType) with a,collect (distinct c) as set1 optional match (a:A)-[:HAS]->(xc:CType) return set1 + collect (distinct xc) as output
```

Comment: Thanks very much - that was very helpful!

Comment: Glad I could help :)